# Unable to create relationships in SSAS 2016 using tabular model programming for compatability level 1200

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssas-tabular

I am trying to create a simple tool that creates a model from metadata. I am successful in creating tables and columns, but unable to create relationships under model. While trying to add FromTable and ToTable properties to relationship object i was getting an error saying those properties are read-only and cannot be changed.

Below is the sample code that i am using to create relationships.

```
public void AddRelationshipsToModel()
    {
        OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = metadataConnInfo.ConnectionString;
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select source_parent_table_name,source_parent_column_name, source_child_table_name,source_child_column_name from HX_VIEWS_RMS.BI_TABULAR_RELATIONSHIPS where MODEL_NAME='"+database.Model.Name +"'";
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                string _toTable =  srcAndTabularTableMap[reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim()];
                string _toColumn = srcTableAndTabularColMap[reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim()][ reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim()];
                string _fromTable = srcAndTabularTableMap[reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Trim()];
                string _fromColumn = srcTableAndTabularColMap[reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Trim()][reader.GetValue(3).ToString().Trim()];

                Table fromTable = Database.Model.Tables[_fromTable];
                DataColumn fromColumn = (DataColumn)fromTable.Columns[_fromColumn];
                Table toTable = Database.Model.Tables[_toTable];
                DataColumn toColumn = (DataColumn)fromTable.Columns[_toColumn];

                SingleColumnRelationship relationship = new SingleColumnRelationship();

                relationship.FromTable = fromTable;
                relationship.FromColumn = fromColumn;
                relationship.ToTable = toTable;
                relationship.ToColumn = toColumn;

                //database.Model.Relationships.Add(new SingleColumnRelationship() { FromColumn = fromColumn ,ToColumn =toColumn});
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](https://andydcutler.wordpress.com/2016/09/19/create-a-ssas-tabular-2016-model-using-the-tabular-object-model/) is a good walk through.

Try just setting the FromColumn and ToColumn properties not the FromTable and ToTable settings. Optionally you can set them as part of the constructor:

```
SingleColumnRelationship relationship = new SingleColumnRelationship()
{
                FromColumn = fromColumn,
                ToColumn = toColumn
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabular object model API has quite a few readonly fields / properties. Basically they are trying to tell you that you are not suppose to edit these fields directly but rather let API fill them for you.

Typical relationship look like this

```
                Server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server();
                [...]
                Server.Databases["MyDatabaseName"].Model.Relationships.Add(new SingleColumnRelationship
                {
                    Name = "Relationship name",
                    FromColumn = Server.Databases["MyDatabaseName"].Model.Tables["FromTableName"].Columns["FromColumnName"],
                    FromCardinality = RelationshipEndCardinality.Many,
                    ToColumn = Server.Databases["MyDatabaseName"].Model.Tables["ToTableName"].Columns["ToColumnName"],
                    ToCardinality = RelationshipEndCardinality.One,
                    CrossFilteringBehavior = CrossFilteringBehavior.BothDirections,
                    IsActive = false
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle with this class - Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.SingleColumnRelationship